# JQuery Datepicker OnSelect not working returns "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have this code, I am using jquery datepicker.
but it won't work. I am trying to set the second datepicker's minDate to the selected date of the first datepicker.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.1.10.4.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.11.1.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.4.css">

<input type="text" id="Inspection_Date">
<input type="text" id="Shipment_Date">

<script>
$(function() {
$( "#Inspection_Date" ).datepicker({
  minDate: 1,
  numberOfMonths: 2,
  onSelect : function(selectedDate) {
        $( "#Shipment_Date" ).datepicker("option","minDate",selectedDate);
    }
  });

$( "#Shipment_Date" ).datepicker({
  minDate: 1,
  numberOfMonths: 2,
  onSelect : function(selectedDate) {
        $( "#Inspection_Date" ).datepicker("option","minDate",selectedDate);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

the console error points to this line of code

```
  $( "#Shipment_Date" ).datepicker("option","maxDate",selectedDate);
```

any help would be appreciated.. thanks

Comment: Can you please provide a fiddle

Comment: It seems that is working properly in [this exemple](https://jsfiddle.net/c4co8mye/) based on what you provided.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kuyakimpoy010/D4AGz/473/

Comment: yes.. but on localhost server it's not working properly..

Comment: @ Kim Carlo have you included `jQuery ui`?

Comment: yes.. i have the libraries included..

Comment: Do you have any 404 in the network tab of the dev tool ?

Comment: @ Kim Carlo why are you including two `jquery-ui` files?

Comment: No errors on the network tab of dev tool

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?